# Add icons indicating locked and protected questions

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions, protected-questions, user-experience

As it stands today, we can clearly see in questions lists when a question is closed. However, there is no way to know if a question is locked or protected, until we actually enter the question page itself.

Can this please be changed by adding a small icon next to the title?

My rough mockup is the following:

- Locked question:

  > [image]
- Protected question:

  > [image]

*<sub>(my initial thought was to add text similar to a closed question, but on second thought that would be too noisy and confusing, hence the above suggestion)</sub>*

Comment: That could be expensive...that info doesn't seem to be available in the Posts table (at least not in SEDE)

Comment: @rene well, there is advanced search operator `locked:1` so this should be efficient to query, however no operator to protected questions so it might be indeed checked per-question. If that's the case, we probably need to ask adding `isprotected:yes` search operator first. :)